# Hide a secret within a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, authentication, mobile, oauth-2.0

I own a mobile app and want it to use my web api. I plan on using the oauth2 user credentials flow (https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/user-credentials/).

However, I want to authenticate the app as well as the user credentials (I don't want any other app or user authenticating to my API for use outside of this app).

I see that the library specifies this:

```
$ curl -u TestClient:TestSecret https://api.mysite.com/token -d 'grant_type=password&username=bshaffer&password=brent123'
```

This will work for me, but it assumes that each mobile app that is downloaded (it is public) will need to have the TestClient:TestSecret preloaded into the app.

How can I ensure that these are not extracted from the app, to allow people to call my API with their user credentials from another app/system etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't if it is pre-loaded. You can only increase the work factor, make it harder and decrease the successful attackers.

One solution is to have the user log into your server and obtain the credentials at that point and them store them in the keychain. Thing about how Dropbox and similar apps handle this problem. But even there keeping the credentials from the user is a difficult problem.

The next issue is Man In The Middle (MITM) attacks, you need to pin the certificate in the app to avoid this.

Comment: Hi zaph, if this is the case then another option is to just add a client key (not key and secret) to the password credentials flow. I guess this is equally secure as its also 'baked' into the app. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, same problem. What you need to do is evaluate the level of security you and your users need. Establish the value of the the data to the user, the attacker, your reputation in $. Establish the attacker you are protecting against: a curious individual, an competent attacker interested in one user or all your data or a well funded government. Evaluate the cost you are will ing to pay in complications, difficulty placed on the user, cost in $ of a Cryptographic security domain expert. Then the protection of the server, 2-factor authentication with hardware that can be tracked by SN?